# Modifying the elements of a list according to a given probability

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Let `list` be a list of lists, the elements of which are random integers in the interval $[1,c]$. Each element $i$ has a probability `prob` to be changed to another integer, selected randomly in $[1,c] \setminus \{v_i\}$ where $v_i$ is the value of the element $i$. No particular size is requested for either `list` or its sublists, but each sublist has the same size.

As an example, let's suppose that **(a)** `list` is made of 3 sublists, **(b)** each sublist contains 2 elements, **(c)** `c` equals to 3, and **(d)** `prob` is 0.25.

A random generation would give for instance `list = {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}}`. After "running" the probability through the elements of the sublists, we would have to change for instance the elements at positions `{1, 2}` and `{3, 1}`. So, `1` will be randomly changed to either `2` or `3`, and `3` to either `1` or `2`. A possible outcome of `list = {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}}` would then be `{{3, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}}`.

I am interested in an efficient way of coding this problem, with the specifications given in the first paragraph.

I tried a method with three different versions, shown below. The respective computing times are given for a problem where **(a)** `list` is made of 1000 sublists, **(b)** each sublist contains 30 elements, **(c)** `c` equals to 3, and **(d)** `prob` is 0.001.

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {1000, 30}];
```

**Version 1**

```
ChangeV1[prob_, c_, sizelist_, sizesublist_][list_] := 
 Block[{elemstochange = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[prob], {sizelist, sizesublist}]},
 ReplacePart[list, (# -> RandomChoice[Drop[Range[c], {Extract[list, #]}]]) 
                     & /@ Position[elemstochange, 1]]];
```

*Timing*

```
ChangeV1[0.001, 3, 1000, 30][list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00297177, Null} *)
```

**Version 2**

```
ChangeV2[prob_, c_, sizelist_, sizesublist_][list_] := 
 Block[{elemstochange = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[prob], {sizelist, sizesublist}]},
 MapAt[RandomChoice[Drop[Range[c], {#}]] &, list, Position[elemstochange, 1]]];
```

*Timing*

```
ChangeV2[0.001, 3, 1000, 30][list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00313513, Null} *)
```

**Version 3**

```
ChangeV3[prob_, c_, sizelist_, sizesublist_][list_] := 
 Block[{elemstochange = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[prob], {sizelist, sizesublist}],
        temp = list},
 (temp[[Sequence @@ #]] = 
  RandomChoice[Drop[Range[c], {Extract[list, #]}]]) & /@ Position[elemstochange, 1];
 temp];
```

*Timing*

```
ChangeV3[0.001, 3, 1000, 30][list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0028965, Null} *)
```

I would be very interested in reading other methods that would improve the computing time for `Change`.

Comment: Is the end result all you're after (hence use of e.g. `Nest` )? If so, seems like a lot of machinations that could be done simply. How big might *c* be?  "Small" (e.g. <thousands) or does it have a large upper bound? What of the probabilities? Will they be "small" as in your test cases, or do they cover the [0,1] space completely?  It would be useful to know more about "...main routine I am working on, there are other functions involved that make modifications..." - what is th purpose of this and the overall goal for the "main" routine - there might be a much more efficient way to get there.

Comment: I reformulated the original question to make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a single-shot adaptation of my earlier (deleted since question changed) ideas. A bit over twice as fast as those *for single-shot cases only*, e.g. on c=5, 5000 sublists, 30 sublist length, p=0.001  done once.

```
mutateList5[list_, c_, p_] := 
 Module[{fl = Flatten@list, cr = Range@c, cl, lfl = Times @@ Dimensions@list, chg},
  cl = Delete[cr, #] & /@ cr;
  chg = RandomSample[Range@lfl, 
    RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[lfl, p]]];
  fl[[chg]] = Extract[cl, Transpose[{fl[[chg]], RandomInteger[{1, c - 1}, Length@chg]}]];
  ArrayReshape[fl, Dimensions@list]];
```

This can be quite a bit faster than above (as in using 2000 sublists of size 30 with *c* of 10 and *p* of 0.1 it was over 50X faster than *ChangeV3* and over 40X faster than *ChangeV1*) :

```
mutateList7[list_, c_, p_, method_: 1] := 
  Block[{th = 50, dl = Dimensions@list, lfl, fl, cr, chg, cn},
   lfl = Times @@ dl;
   cn = Switch[method, 1, RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[lfl, p]],
                       2, Tr@RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], lfl],
                       3, RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[lfl*p]]];
   Which[cn == 0, list,
    cn <= th,
    chg = RandomSample[Range@lfl, cn];
    chg = Transpose[{Ceiling[chg/dl[[2]]], Mod[chg, dl[[2]], 1]}];
    cr = Range@(c - 1);
    ReplacePart[list, Thread[chg -> Mod[Extract[list, chg] + RandomChoice[cr, cn], c, 1]]],
    True,
    fl = Flatten@list;
    cr = Range@(c - 1);
    chg = RandomSample[Range@lfl, cn];
    fl[[chg]] = Mod[fl[[chg]] + RandomChoice[cr, cn], c, 1];
    ArrayReshape[fl, Dimensions@list]]];
```

Uses heuristics to optimize strategy for changes. This also uses an optional last argument that uses differing methods for change determination. I've found some... interesting behavior of Binomial RV generation, where it was much slower for your test case than made sense, and summing Bernoulli was much faster, yet on larger cases it was fast as expected. I'm investigating this, I'd venture it's some auto-compilation or internal algorithm switch depending on parameters.

In any case, try them out. Method 1 (default) uses Binomial, 2 uses sum of Bernoulli, and method 3 uses Poisson RV, which can be very fast and is appropriate when number of elements * probability <= 10 to 20 or so.

As an aside, you've still not clarified what happens to parameters between calls for a given "run" of your "thing", i.e., does *c* change? Does *p* change? Is it called with differing contents and perhaps dimensions, but *p* or *c*, or both, are constant? If any of these are true, significant speed gains can be had...

Update: Per comments, here's a potentially much more efficient means to the end:

```
mutateBldr[c_, p_, sl_, sls_, mr_] := 
  Module[{rv, rvf, rvc = 1, ts, cr, fn, th = 100},
   rv = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[sl sls, p], mr];
   ts = Tuples[{Range@sl, Range@sls}];
   rvf = Range@(sl*sls);
   cr = Range@(c - 1);
   fn = If[rv[[rvc]] == 0, rvc++; #, Block[{t, m},
       If[rv[[rvc]] > th, m = Flatten@#;
        t = RandomSample[rvf, rv[[rvc]]];
        m[[t]] = Mod[m[[t]] + RandomChoice[cr, rv[[rvc++]]], c, 1];
        Partition[m, sls],
        t = RandomSample[ts, rv[[rvc]]];
        ReplacePart[#, Thread[t -> Mod[Extract[#, t] + RandomChoice[cr, rv[[rvc++]]], c, 1]]]]]] &;
   fn];
```

Use: Prime it with the specific *c, # sublists, sublist size, and probability*, along with expected runs (so if you're going to call it say 1000 times, use 1500 or so to give wiggle-room):

```
mymute = mutateBldr[c, prob, subLists, subListSz, 10000];
```

Then, just call it on your evolving lists:

```
mutatedlist=mymute[currentlist];
```

I think you'll find this significantly outperforms prior methods...

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot @ciao. The method with `Mod` is nice and the use of a Poisson distribution is a good idea. About your questions, for a given run of the "main" function, `c`, `p` and the dimensions of `list` are constant. Only the contents of the sublists within `list` can change. (One way they change is from mutations (with `mutateList`), the other is from crossovers – I am considering a genetic algorithm).

Comment: @Xavier Cool. So, if you need that last sliver of speed, you could build a function that takes p c and dims, precomputes the quantiles and other giblets and returns a function that you use for runs for those parameters. I'd venture you could double performance or so...

Comment: @Xavier - just cobbled up a quick-n-dirty of a pre-computed version, turns out it's over an order of magnitude faster... worth pursuing for you prehaps.

Comment: Ah that's very nice @ciao. Thanks for the tip, I'll add that.

Comment: @Xavier: Added the pre-computed version, give it a whirl and report back...

Comment: Thanks for the update @ciao. If I get it correctly, your code uses the temporary symbols generated by `Module`, with assigned values, as external/global parameters for the function with `Block`. This is clever. I don't think I've ever used such a method before. I'll run this version to see the timings and report back.

Comment: @Xavier: Thanks for pointing out typo - fixed. Yes, your read is correct. In essence: setup/teardown of random functions can be expensive in MMA (in some cases very expensive). So, generating K random variates at once will be *much, much* faster than generating K random variates one at a time. So, we pre-load the function with enough needed randomized pieces and giblets by doing the work in bulk (and hence quickly), and use that in the actual calls for mutation. Depending on list sizes, c, and probability, performance boost of up to 100X was seen in a few tests I did.

Comment: @Xavier: added a couple of minor optimizations to shave off some microseconds...

Comment: ciao, I runned your two last versions of `mutateBldr` in several configurations. They are very fast compared to my codes, and the improvement can be very large indeed. They behave nicely when modifying the parameters. Thanks for the information about the random functions. I'll definitely use your method to improve my code for the crossover part of the algo.

Answer (score 3):

In the narrowly defined interpretation of the question, one can get an incremental speed gain by flattening the lists, and reshaping the result to the desired dimensions afterwards:

```
ChangeV4[prob_, c_, sizelist_, sizesublist_][list_] := 
  Block[{elemstochange = 
     RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[prob], 
      sizelist sizesublist],
    temp = Flatten@list,
    choices = Table[Drop[Range[c], {i}], {i, c}]
    },
   (temp[[#]] = RandomChoice[choices[[temp[[#]]]]]) & /@ 
    Flatten@Position[elemstochange, 1];
   Partition[temp, sizesublist]];
```

Here, I also tried to get another small gain in efficiency by taking the operation `Drop[Range[c],...]` out of the "loop" over the elements to change.

In my test with `list` as given in the question, this performed faster than all three original versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jens and the ideas with `Flatten` and `Drop`.